# ComputeChangeSet(): should it returns owning side collection changes?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Follow this example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(...)   
 * @ORM\Entity(...)
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo")
     */
    protected $bars;

    //setters and getters omitted
}
```

In Doctrine2, should

```
$cs = $this->computeChangeSet(
    $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($foo)),
    $foo
);
```

returns `['bars']` if `$bars` is changed?

I'm asking this because, as far as I know, doctrine2 looks only for owning side changes

Comment: Good question. Maybe it still registers changes in a change set, but when persisting it realizes these changes don't need to be persisted?

Comment: @Wilt testing it, returns anything about owning side. That force me to store "previous" collection before bind object with new form values. Of course I'm aware of doctrine2 preUpdate() event